# Objective-c addObject in loop causes memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have found a similar issue:
[NSMutableArray addObject in for loop - memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180787/nsmutablearray-addobject-in-for-loop-memory-leak)

But none of those suggestions seem to fix my problem.

I have a simple loop where I'm creating an object and adding it to an array. When I try to release the object at the end of each loop the app crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". If I don't release the object I get leaked memory:

In .h

```
NSMutableArray *mainlist;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mainList;
```

In .m

```
@synthesize mainlist;
...

for (int i = 0; i < [self.objects count]; i++) {

    MyObj *myObj = [[MyObj alloc] init];

    myObj.title = [[self.objects objectAtIndex: i] valueForKey: @"title"];

    [self.mainlist addObject:myObj];

    [myObj release]; // crashes with release
}
```

MyObj just has some properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *date_text;
...
@synthesize title;
@synthesize date_text;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];

    [title release];
    [date_text release];
}

@end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your `init` message for `MyObj`?

Comment: Did you override *init* method in *MyObj* class?

Comment: I've updated the code above. There's no init method. just getters/setters. Does it need it?

Comment: Shouldnt you do [super dealloc] after your other releases instead of before?

Comment: It would help if you posted the stack for the crash as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crashes cause you first call dealloc of superclass and then try to release attributes. Change this to:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [date_text release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

And also: I'm almost certain that your self.mainlist is nil, when you're adding objects there. Creating a property doesn't mean that the attribute would be initialized automatically.