# How can i copy a MutableArray in the same zone as the old one?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, objective-c-2.0, copywithzone

How can i add a mutable array in the same like the old one?

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
 - (void)didParsingApiBusinesses:(NSMutableArray *)businesses
 {
     NSZone *zone = [entriesBusinessesArray zone];
     entriesBusinessesArray = [businesses mutableCopyWithZone:zone];
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002174/copy-mutablecopy

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Zones aren't used by the framework anymore.
2. You shouldn't call `mutableCopyWithZone:` directly; instead call `mutableCopy`.

So all you need is:

```
- (void)didParsingApiBusinesses:(NSMutableArray *)businesses
{
    entriesBusinessesArray = [businesses mutableCopy];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mutableCopy directly.

I think NSZone is not supported by objective C now.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, `NSZone` is in the Foundation framework. It's not part of the Objective-C language.