# NSMutablearray crashes deleting object

Tags: ios, crash, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I run a for to choose which objects to remove. After i removed one the app crashes. 
I´ve read that i couldn´t remove an object in the for because of the index, so i remove them outside but it still crashes. When it crashes at runtime it says the array it is an NSArray which is not, it is a NSMutablearray. Anyone knows why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger catalogo = [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"catalogo"] intValue];
NSInteger documento = [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"documento"] intValue];

for (i=0; i<[self.deletedDocuments count] ; i++) 
{
    if ([[[self.deletedDocuments objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"documento"] intValue] == documento &&
        [[[self.deletedDocuments objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"catalogo"] intValue] == catalogo) 
        [discardedItems addObject:[self.deletedDocuments objectAtIndex:i]];
}

NSLog(@"Dictionary\n%@", self.deletedDocuments);
if (discardedItems != nil)
    [self.deletedDocuments removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you storing the array in user defaults? objects taken from user defaults will be immutable, even if a mutable subclass was stored

Comment: Yes, i am... So that is the problem. So, now how do i save them? And be able to remove them?

Comment: make mutableCopy perhaps?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002174/copy-mutablecopy

Comment: @ade is right, just do something like [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SomeKey"] mutableCopy];

Answer (score 0):

> When it crashes at runtime it says the array it is an NSArray which is not, it is a NSMutablearray.

No, if the runtime says its an `NSArray`, it's an `NSArray`. Make sure you don't assign an NSArray to `NSMutableArray * deletedDocuments` variable. Note that it's `deletedDocuments` that is `NSArray`, not `discardedItems`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for (int i=[self.deletedDocuments count]-1; i>=0 ; i--) 
{
    if ([[[self.deletedDocuments objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"documento"] intValue] == documento &&
    [[[self.deletedDocuments objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"catalogo"] intValue] == catalogo) {
        [self.deletedDocuments removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
}
```