# Does Objective-C have C++11 rvalue references and move semantics equivalents or how to implement this?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics

I'm in the process of learning Objective-C. And I have such an "academical" question which is addressed to Objective-C experts with good knowledge of modern C++ (C++11).

In C++11 I often used move semantics (using references to temporary objects we can avoid unnecessary copies):
[What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me)
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html

these links for objective-c coders not familiar with move semantics concept, and I'm interested does Objective-C has something similar or may be there are some ways to implement/emulate this?

Comment: I don't understand what "object semantics" vs "value semantics" are. Is this something you made up? If so, please explain more clearly what you're after.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the questioner hasn't made it up, but the thing that I assume he means by "object semantics" I would call "entity semantics". In short a type with entity semantics has a concept of *object identity* which is useful/meaningful/whatever to users of the type, whereas a type with value semantics you would expect only to be compared by value with `==`. Obviously the difference can become blurred, it's a design goal rather than a strict property of the type. In C++ it often goes with the difference between a copyable vs non-copyable type: entities are not routinely copied.

Comment: Retag your question. I believe it is Objective-C question, not C++ question, C++ might be secondary tag, and [equivalent] is misleading. Ask Objective-C experts with assumption they could know only a little about C++11, so explain in more details what you want to achieve in Objective-C. 

I know almost nothing about Objective-C - but maybe this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002174/copy-mutablecopy

Comment: @Alexander if you describe these C++11 features in a way that will be somehow understable for non C++ experts - then Objective-C experts  will be able to help. You will have wider audience then, more chance to succeed. The best would be to describe what you want to do in Objective-C - with referring to C++ as little as possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does Objective-C has something similar or may be there are some ways to implement/emulate this?

Nope. That's not a huge issue, once you have digested the abstraction layer you are working at with Objective-C. Understand that objects are reference counted and are heap allocations.

Now there are two ways you can take this:

a) Use Objective-C++ -- Just mix and match the language features to your content.

b) Use idiomatic Objective-C. This goes back a long time. Once you accept that objects are reference counted heap allocations and there is no way around that (with clang), then you learn to approach programs differently. Sure, reference counting everything and putting it on the heap has costs, but you can take advantage of those traits in some scenarios. The most notable uses are the use of immutable objects and shallow copying. Copying a `std::string` as object is going to result in SSO copy or a heap allocation. Copying an `NSString` could simply return itself (after incrementing the reference count or not, depending on the type of string it is, it may also need to create a concrete copy at that point). As well, these objects are all just pointers, so you don't need to actively be concerned with how to pass an object (value/reference/const reference/move). A far simpler model exists in ObjC, which can be exploited. So there is a shift in design here: there is less "value dominance" in ObjC and more of "favor immutability and sharing".

In some cases, you can write a move method. Since common framework classes do not support this, it typically makes more sense to use object composition.

Since objects are allocated on the heap, moves are not so important. Well designed classes take costs into consideration to minimize huge/expensive copies, and internally use some interesting optimizations. The idiom just suggests that you should take a different approach to creating your classes -- how do they share data? What is mutable? What must be copied? Sometimes, you might be dealing with big, mutable/expensive data and a move would be convenient, but you could often just place that in a shared container object or reconsider semantics of your objects' initialization in order to minimize physical copying (and avoid odd semantics in object interfaces). Beyond that, I don't see moves as being very useful all too often in pure Objective-C. Of course, they become important for C++ libraries which have been designed to make use of move semantics and are able to create objects in several memory locations. If you do move, you would usually want to keep that detail private or make it really obvious (e.g. I have done that in a rendering pipeline to minimize big allocations for each filter).

Examples of where you think it would be beneficial would also help understand your problem/rationale.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C does not have these features just as C does not, because Objective-C is a specific set of features on top of pure C. Objective-C++ does have these features because it's the same set of features on top of C++.

One of the things that makes move semantics so important in C++ is C++'s strong emphasis on value semantics. Typically you don't hold pointers to C++ objects, you hold C++ objects by value. Without move semantics this results in lots of unnecessary copies.

Not only does Objective-C not place the same emphasis on value semantics, it completely prohibits value semantics for Objective-C objects; you can only create Objective-C objects dynamically, you cannot copy an object the way you can copy C structs, etc.

```
@interface Foo
@end
@implementation Foo
@end

int main() {
    Foo f;
    Foo *a, *b;
    *a = *b;
}

error: interface type cannot be statically allocated
Foo f;
    ^
    *
error: cannot assign to class object ('Foo' invalid)
*a = *b;
   ^
```

So the C++ concept of references and moving is all done the C way in Objective-C, with pointers. Of course this means that C++ has many of the same performance advantages over Objective-C as it does over C, due to the same ability to avoid pointers.