# Insert new array to NSMutabbleArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a json parser with `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

my parsing code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

and I have a `NSMutableArray`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * myDirectory;
```

First, I load main 10 items and add with this:

```
self.myDirectory = responseObject;
```

After, when I want to load more 10 items, I tried many things but error is:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]:
mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I tried:

```
[self.myDirectory insertObject:[responseObject mutableCopy] atIndex:[self.myDirectory count]];
[self.myDirectory addObjects:responseObject];
etc...
```

What I must use?

Comment: The error is telling you that the receiver of `insertObject:atIndex` is immutable.  Likely, you should be assigning `myDirectory` property differently, e.g. `self.myDirectory = [responseObject mutableCopy]` to insure that it's mutable

Comment: You don't have an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking returns immutable arrays (NSArray), so you must assign it like:

```
self.myDirectory = [responseObject mutableCopy]
```

Comment: Try replacing the line I put as answer with: self.myDirectory ? [self.myDirectory addObjectsFromArray:responseObject] : self.myDirectory = responseObject;

Comment: same error: [__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Answer (score 0):

did you try `[myArray addObjectsFromArray:otherArray];`

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking returns immutable arrays. So try this:

```
self.myDirectory = [responseObject mutableCopy];
```

When you want to add the second `responseObject` to previous `self.myDirectory` try this:

```
[self.myDirectory addObjectsFromArray: responseObject];
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002174/copy-mutablecopy) for a clear concept about `copy` and `mutableCopy`.

Hope this helps.. :)

**EDIT:**

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B", nil];
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"C",@"D", nil];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"E",@"F", nil];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
mutableArray = [arr mutableCopy];
[mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:arr1];
[mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:arr2];
NSLog(@"%@",mutableArray);
```

Comment: I tried, first is removing first items, your second code is not working, same error again.

Comment: Try this: [self.myDirectory addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject mutableCopy]]; Let me know.

Comment: again error: [__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: I have many data object type in my application.
For example; id, title, author, date, hits, photo, updated_date, etc... should I create initwithObjects for all?

Comment: are they array or dictionary?

Comment: !!! Its not an array, Its a Dictionary. Thats why you are getting this error. If you share your whole dictionary and tell me what you want then I might help.

Comment: sorry but I said first post, its a json. first parsing responseObject can add nsmutabblearray, why second (insert new items) dont work?
you are saying its a Dictionary, but I think not. Because AFNetwork AFJSONResponseSerializer converted. Please check my first post again. thanks.

Comment: Can you please post you JSON?

Comment: [{"id":1,"title":"Title Test","cat":"cat Title","date":"2014"},{"id":2,"title":"Title Test","cat":"cat Title","date":"2014"},{"id":3,"title":"Title Test","cat":"cat Title","date":"2014"},{"id":4,"title":"Title Test","cat":"cat Title","date":"2014"}]

Comment: Its an array of NSDictionary.

Comment: so, what I should do?

Comment: Share your code. Because I think you are doing something wrong in code. The above solution should work.